# SQL Server Query Results in Duplicate Results for election Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates, normalizing

I have a complete database system that is primarily used with it's own frontend software. This year our character generator only accepts XML data feeds, and I have found that I can query the database and create an XML file.

The database is spread across about a dozen tables. I can get all the information I want to air from a 2 table query, but am afraid I will need 3.

My first few queries bring up a `RACE`, each race has 2 candidates, but when I run the query it shows a record for each candidate (times 2). So I have 2 rows titled `RACE NUMBER 101`. Each row has BOTH candidates in it, their votes (which are related by their unique candidate #, and is in another table), precints reporting, vote percentage..etc.

I am trying to get one race within one ROW. One row, that will show the race title, both candidates, their votes, their vote percents and the precincts reporting.

The query I have written is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[RACE] 
INNER JOIN dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] ON [RACE].[race number] = [RACE CANDIDATES].[race number]
```

This gives me a complete overview of all fields I am able to query, but they are showing 2 rows from the same RACE#. Also, it shows the candidate's unique # along with their # of votes. But again, these are all in 2 rows. The only 2 differences I can see in the rows queried is the candidate's unique ID and their vote number.

I would like to get both candidate's names, number of votes and voter percentage in ONE single row, so I can make it an XML PATH, in a single block. One race, all race elements under one XML category.

It is driving me nuts. It is very hard to ask a question like this, especially on a subject like this. I have the database saved off as a `*.bak` file that I have been able to load on 3 different machines now, so I have that available if anyone would like to take a look. There is no confidential data within it, so I have no problem offering it up.

I have about 30 hours SOLID into this. I see hope, but then I end up back where I started.

Usually, I would just send the data line by line to the character generator serially, but our graphics system has changed since the last primary election.

If anyone could give me an idea of what the right questions to ask would be I would appreciate it. This of course is for work and the whole weight of this data feed is on my shoulders, I am reaching out to where ever I can with a broken limb.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Please give a sample of the data, the results you are getting, and desired results.

Comment: Based on the syntax of the sample query, I am tagging this as SQL Server.

Comment: I tried to add parts of the schema below.

I am getting 2 rows for each race. I beleive that each row is for each candidate. since the only difference is the Candidate's unique# and their votes.

I would like one single row that has all the race info, including each candidates name and their total votes. The only queries I have been able to produce result in two rows of the same race....but with different vote totals and different candidate numbers. 

Both rows show both candidates twice. (Each row has 2 sets of the candidates name.) Driving me crazy! ha.

Comment: Ha! This must be Florida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are getting one row for each candidate in the race.  You need to pivot the data.

Here is one way, that puts the one with the most votes first:

```
SELECT r.*, Winner, WinningVotes, Loser, LosingVotes
FROM dbo.[RACE] r inner join
     (select rc.[race number],
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then CandidateNumber end) as Winner,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then Votes end) as WinningVotes,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then CandidateNumber end) as Loser,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then Votes end) as LosingVotes
      from (select rc.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by rc.[race number] order by votes desc) as seqnum
            from dbo.[RACE CANDIDATES] rc
           ) rc
      group by rc.[race number]
     ) rc
     on r.[race number] = rc.[race number] ;
```

The function `row_number()` is a window function.  It will assign the value of 1 to the candidate with the most votes and 2 to the second candidate.

Comment: This is great but it still shows 2 races for a single race. This gives me more to work off of for sure. Thanks!

Comment: @user3242661 . . . I left outer the `group by` in the subquery.  Fixed.

Comment: I have tried to left outer the group by, but I am not sure I am following you. Query not running correctly. I apprecate your help and time.

Comment: YES! This has put everything in one row! now I need to narrow all the fields down to what I really need.

Comment: Could you possibly explain a little on what the
r.* is doing?

And how I could identify the winning votes and losing votes directly with the individual candidate?

Thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: The `r.*` is simply taking all the fields from the `race` table.  `r` is a table alias, a shorthand for the reference.  This query identifies the winning candidate and the winning number of votes, so I don't understand the other half of the question.

Comment: Maybe the other half shouldn't have been asked. The feed will be "fed" to static fields, so I will just translate the XML with the xsl file to fit my needs. That is what I thought the r.* was doing. I am going to start manipulating that statement, as I only need 8 fields from this whole database to accomplish the on-air result. Plus, I will need to alias a few of the fields so they can be PATHED as XML. PATH does not like "spaces" in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

If all the fields of your rows are the same (except id and number of votes), you can group them by, in example, the raceName (or another field that you want). Something like this, but if you don't provide the schema I can't help you more:

```
SELECT r.raceName, rc.*
  FROM race r
  INNER JOIN race_candidates rc
          ON race.race_number= race_candidates.race_number
GROUP BY r.raceName
```

Comment: Can I email you the schema? It is much too large for the forum.

Comment: You should post here for community benefit. Further, we don't need all the schema, only the tables related to your problem

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CANDIDATE]    Script Date: 01/27/2014 19:44:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CANDIDATE](
 [candidate number] [int] IDENTITY(5000,1) NOT NULL,
 [party] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [first name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [last name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [initial] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [talent] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [cother1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [cother2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [cother3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [logo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CANDIDATE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [candidate number] ASC
)

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RACE CANDIDATES]    Script Date: 01/27/2014 19:44:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RACE CANDIDATES](
 [race number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [candidate num] [int] NOT NULL,
 [votes] [int] NOT NULL,
 [winner] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [wire ID] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [incumbent] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [order] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [projected winner] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RACE_CANDIDATES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [race number] ASC,
 [candidate num] ASC
)

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RACE]    Script Date: 01/27/2014 19:44:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RACE](
 [race number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [sum results] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [fix percents] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [winners] [smallint] NULL,
 [maximum vote] [int] NOT NULL,
 [default cg] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [title1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [title2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [title3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [talent1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [talent2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [talent3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [wire id1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,

Comment: [total precincts] [int] NOT NULL,
 [precincts reporting] [int] NULL,
 [last update] [int] NULL,
 [last update producer] [int] NULL,
 [last air] [int] NULL,
 [last lead change] [int] NULL,
 [last winner change] [int] NULL,
 [total vote] [int] NULL,
 [change vote] [int] NULL,
 [report_to_1] [int] NULL,
 [report_to_2] [int] NULL,
 [report_to_3] [int] NULL,
 [other1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,

Comment: [other2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [other3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [other4] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 [winners selected] [smallint] NULL,
 [max probable] [smallint] NULL,
 [precinct percent] [smallint] NULL,
 [yesno1] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [yesno2] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [yesno3] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [yesno4] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [autowin precinct] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [autowin both] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 [wire winner] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [leader] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[leader percent] [smallint] NULL,
 [leader2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [leader2 percent] [smallint] NULL,
 [sort by party] [bit] NOT NULL,

Comment: [airable] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [reports from] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RACE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [race number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 

ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LIST RACES]    Script Date: 01/27/2014 19:44:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LIST RACES](
 [group number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [race num] [int] NOT NULL,
 [counter] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [order] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LIST RACES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [group number] ASC,
 [race num] ASC,
 [counter] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 

ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PRECINCT RESULTS]    Script Date: 01/27/2014 19:44:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRECINCT RESULTS](
 [group number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [race number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [candidate num] [int] NOT NULL,
 [votes] [int] NULL,
 [winner] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [counter] [int] NOT NULL,
 [projected winner] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PRECINCT_RESULTS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [group number] ASC,
 [race number] ASC,
 [candidate num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX= OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,

Comment: I wish I would have looked at this schema myself.

Comment: @user3242661 Oh, egads, please stop dumping code in comments. Update your question with this information. Please.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the interface. I appologize for my ignorance.